# Centre on page a central piece of tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, overlays

I would like to centre on page the key element of a tikzpicture, while callouts, explanatory text would not affect the position of the key element.

I devised this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\par
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (imagenode) at (0, 0)[anchor = center]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
  \node(additions) at (imagenode.east)[anchor = west]{Explanation};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

From the output

[image]

one can see that the

> Explanation

caused a displacement of the image from its central location.

How to fix?

Comment: A dirty workaround would be do add a `\phantom{Explanation}` or `\textcolor{white}{Explanation}` on the left side. Just putting it here for the record `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option in such cases is overlay... It never affects the normal layer positions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\par
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (imagenode) at (0, 0)[anchor = center]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
  \node[overlay](additions) at (imagenode.east)[anchor = west]{Explanation};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It works without `[remember picture]`. Why does one need it?

Comment: You are right... I just thought that it has te remember the picture to use its node in the overlay... but in this case the node and the overlay was in the same tikzpicture... So I will edit to delete it. You could and should use it if it was not in the same tikzpicture